# Concurrent reading and writing to IOArray in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc

I am getting my feet wet writing concurrent programs in Haskell with GHC for multicore machines. As a first step I decided to write a program that reads and writes concurrently to an IOArray. I had the impression that reads and writes to IOArray involve no synchronization. I'm doing this to establish a baseline to compare with the performance of other data structures that do use appropriate synchronization mechanisms. I ran in to some surprising results, namely that in many cases, I am not getting any speed up at all. This makes me wonder if there is some low level synchronization happening in the ghc runtime, for example, synchronization and blocking on evaluation of thunks (i.e. "black holes"). Here are the details...

I write a couple variations on a single program. The main idea is that I wrote a DirectAddressTable data structure, which is simply a wrapper around an IOArray providing insert and lookup methods:

```
-- file DirectAddressTable.hs
module DirectAddressTable 
       ( DAT
       , newDAT
       , lookupDAT
       , insertDAT
       , getAssocsDAT
       )
       where

import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.MArray

newtype DAT = DAT (IOArray Int Char)

-- create a fixed size array; missing keys have value '-'.
newDAT :: Int -> IO DAT
newDAT n = do a <- newArray (0, n - 1) '-'
              return (DAT a)

-- lookup an item.
lookupDAT :: DAT -> Int -> IO (Maybe Char)
lookupDAT (DAT a) i = do c <- readArray a i 
                         return (if c=='-' then Nothing else Just c)

-- insert an item
insertDAT :: DAT -> Int -> Char -> IO ()
insertDAT (DAT a) i v = writeArray a i v

-- get all associations (exclude missing items, i.e. those whose value is '-').
getAssocsDAT :: DAT -> IO [(Int,Char)]
getAssocsDAT (DAT a) = 
  do assocs <- getAssocs a
     return [ (k,c) | (k,c) <- assocs, c /= '-' ]
```

I then have a main program that initializes a new table, forks some threads, with each thread writing and reading some fixed number of values to the just initialized table. The overall number of elements to write is fixed. The number of threads to use is a taken from a command line argument, and the elements to process are evenly divided among the threads.

```
-- file DirectTableTest.hs
import DirectAddressTable
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Parallel
import System.Environment

main = 
  do args <- getArgs
     let numThreads = read (args !! 0)
     vs <- sequence (replicate numThreads newEmptyMVar)
     a <- newDAT arraySize     
     sequence_ [ forkIO (doLotsOfStuff numThreads i a >>= putMVar v) 
               | (i,v) <- zip [1..] vs]
     sequence_ [ takeMVar v >>= \a -> getAssocsDAT a >>= \xs -> print (last xs)  
               | v <- vs]     

doLotsOfStuff :: Int -> Int -> DAT -> IO DAT
doLotsOfStuff numThreads i a = 
  do let p j c = (c `seq` insertDAT a j c) >> 
                 lookupDAT a j >>= \v -> 
                 v `pseq` return ()  
     sequence_ [ p j c | (j,c) <- bunchOfKeys i ]
     return a
  where  bunchOfKeys i = take numElems $ zip cyclicIndices $ drop i cyclicChars
         numElems      = numberOfElems `div` numThreads

cyclicIndices = cycle [0..highestIndex]
cyclicChars   = cycle chars
chars         = ['a'..'z']

-- Parameters
arraySize :: Int
arraySize     = 100
highestIndex  = arraySize - 1
numberOfElems = 10 * 1000 * 1000
```

I compiled this using ghc 7.2.1 (similar results with 7.0.3) with "ghc --make -rtsopts -threaded  -fforce-recomp -O2 DirectTableTest.hs". 
Running "time ./DirectTableTest 1 +RTS -N1" takes about 1.4 seconds and running "time ./DirectTableTest 2 +RTS -N2" take about 2.0 seconds! Using one more core than worker threads is a little better, with "time ./DirectTableTest 1 +RTS -N1" takes about 1.4 seconds and running "time ./DirectTableTest 1 +RTS -N2" and "time ./DirectTableTest 2 +RTS -N3" both taking about 1.4 seconds.
Running with the "-N2 -s" option shows that productivity is 95.4% and GC is 4.3%. Looking at a run of the program with ThreadScope I don't see anything too alarming. Each HEC yields once per ms when a GC occurs. Running with 4 cores gives a time of about 1.2 seconds, which is at least a little better than 1 core. More cores doesn't improve over this.

I found that changing the array type used in the implementation of DirectAddressTable from IOArray to IOUArray fixes this problem. With this change, the running time of "time ./DirectTableTest 1 +RTS -N1" is about 1.4 seconds whereas the running "time ./DirectTableTest 2 +RTS -N2" is about 1.0 seconds. Increasing to 4 cores gives a run time of 0.55 seconds. Running with "-s" shows a GC time of %3.9 percent. Under ThreadScope I can see that both threads yield every 0.4 ms, more frequently than in the previous program.

Finally, I tried one more variation. Instead of having the threads work on the same shared array, I had each thread work on its own array. This scales nicely (as you would expect), more or less like the second program, with either IOArray or IOUArray implementing the DirectAddressTable data structure.

I understand why IOUArray might perform better than IOArray, but I don't know why it scales better to multiple threads and cores. Does anyone know why this might be happening or what I can do to find out what is going on? I wonder if this problem could be due to multiple threads blocking while evaluating the same thunk and whether it is related to this: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3838 .

Comment: Not sure about the real answer, but is that `(j, c) <- bunchOfKeys j` in `doLotsOfStuff` really right? The `j` variable you're supplying to `bunchOfKeys` doesn't look like it's in scope to me.

Comment: Daniel: Thanks for catching that; it should have been `bunchOfKeys i`. I fixed that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

> Running "time ./DirectTableTest 1 +RTS -N1" takes about 1.4 seconds and running "time ./DirectTableTest 2 +RTS -N2" take about 2.0 seconds!

I can not reproduce your results:

```
$ time ./so2 1 +RTS -N1
(99,'k')

real    0m0.950s
user    0m0.932s
sys     0m0.016s
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so2 2 +RTS -N2
(99,'s')
(99,'s')

real    0m0.589s
user    0m1.136s
sys     0m0.024s
```

And this seems to scale as expected as the number of light weight threads increases too:

```
ghc -O2 so2.hs -threaded -rtsopts
[1 of 2] Compiling DirectAddressTable2 ( DirectAddressTable2.hs, DirectAddressTable2.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( so2.hs, so2.o )
Linking so2 ...
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so2 4
(99,'n')
(99,'z')
(99,'y')
(99,'y')

real    0m1.538s
user    0m1.320s
sys     0m0.216s
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so2 4 +RTS -N2
(99,'z')
(99,'x')
(99,'y')
(99,'y')

real    0m0.600s
user    0m1.156s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Do you actually have 2 CPUs?  If you run with more GHC threads (`-Nx`) than you have available CPUs then your results will be very poor.  What I think I'm really asking is: are you sure no other CPU intensive processes are running on your system?

**As for the IOUArray** (by edit)

> I understand why IOUArray might perform better than IOArray, but I don't know why it scales better to multiple threads and cores

An unboxed array will be contiguous and thus benefit much more from caching.  Boxed values living in arbitrary locations on the heap could cause a large increase in cache invalidations between the cores.

Comment: Thanks. The machine I ran the program on is indeed a multicore machine (12 cores) running ubuntu. I ran the program again on a different machine (MacBook) with two cores and got the results that you did (i.e. good scaling). So it seems that my understanding of concurrent access to IOArray was more or less right, and the issue is a platform-specific problem.